# Closing Dialog in Fragment will remove fragment itself

Tags: android, android-fragments

I open a Dialog when I click on a button inside a **DialogFragment**:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyFragment.this.getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Remove?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dismiss();
        }

    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

When I press cancel button on Dialog, the whole fragment disappears.

MyFragment is a **DialgFragment** and I think this is the cause of error.

Now question is how to dismiss a Dialog inside a DialogFragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line

```
dismiss();
```

with

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

You are inside `DialogFragment`.
From this [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#dismiss%28%29) `dismiss()` will remove the `DialogFragment` instead of `Dialog`.

Comment: Based on my source, what is `dialog` here?

Comment: In this method onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) **DialogInterface dialog** object  is dialog

Comment: Wow! Sorry for my dumb comment!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use either [Dialog.dismiss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29), or [Dialog.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel%28%29)